# Change name of list of algorithms in algorithmicx

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

This works for algorithm title:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Something else}
\makeatother
```

Nothing I have found on the internet works for list of algorithms. It's either error or list just stops displaying.

Edit

Minimal working example in case someone forgot how blank latex project looks like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\listofalgorithms %displays as List of Algorithms, I want it to be something else

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the `\listalgorithmname` macro with what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{something else}

\begin{document}
  
  \section{Introduction}
  
  \listofalgorithms %displays as List of Algorithms, I want it to be something else
  
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
    \label{alg1}
  \end{algorithm}
  
  
\end{document}
```

Which produces desired result.
[image]